# Add each row from text file in separate textboxes in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 30+ TextBoxes in my application and I would like to add, in order, each row of the text file in each textbox.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (path1 != null && Directory.Exists(path1))
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path1);
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            //what is here ?
        }
    }
}
```

So, if I have in my text file:
 - dog
 - computer
 - money

I would like to have in:

- **textbox1** the **first row** (dog)
- **textbox2** the **second row** (computer)
- **textbox3** the **third row** (money)

**Update:** Added a list of `TextBoxes`. Now, how can I access one textbox at a time and use it in `foreach` ?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<TextBox> textBoxes = new List<TextBox>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 37; i++)
    {
        textBoxes.Add((TextBox)Controls.Find("textBox" + i, true)[0]);
    }

    if (path1 != null && Directory.Exists(path1))
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path1);
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            //what is here ?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add all textboxes to a list. In the foreach you can access it.

Comment: @cSteusloff I added a list. Could you answer me to the last updated question ? A snippet would be great.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to solve by this? So far it looks like a bad decision to be honest...

Comment: I am trying to print those lines and then, to access each of them ( each row will be a link). More, I need them printed out somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the foreach to a for and use the index to access the current line as well as the designated textbox:

```
if (path1 != null && File.Exists(path1))
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path1);
    for (var lineIndex = 0; lineIndex < Math.Min(lines.Length, textBoxes.Count); lineIndex++)
    {
        textBoxes[lineIndex].Text = lines[lineIndex];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. It doesn't print anything though.

Comment: I think "Directory.Exists(path1)" is your problem. It will return false if path1 is a file name and therefore the block is not executed. I corrected it to File.Exists in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your foreach loop, try this:

```
var textBoxIndex = 0;
foreach (var line in lines)
{
   textBoxes[textBoxIndex++].Text = line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my suggestion

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string Path1 = "MyFile.txt";

    List<TextBox> textBoxes = new List<TextBox>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }        

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
        {
            if (item is TextBox)
            {
                textBoxes.Add((TextBox)item);
            }
        }

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Path1);

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; ++i)
        {
            textBoxes[i].Text = lines[i];
        }         
    }
}
```

Comment: or you can put all textboxes on a flowLayoutPanel and in foreach loop write "Control item in this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls" @alexander

Comment: I assume that text file exists and isn't null  @Alexander